# Tool which can do both UML and ER Diagram

Tags: uml, diagram, entity-relationship

I have approval to buy one tool which can help programmers of my team to write better code.

Most of my team members either do UML (.NET developers) or they do ER (database developers)

Can you please recommend a tool for me which can do both of these type of diagrams?

Please don't recommend Visio because my team already evaluated it and everyone disliked it as either a UML or ER diagram tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout:

- [Concept Draw](http://www.conceptdraw.com/en/products/cd5/applications_uml.php)
- [Visual Paradigm uml tool](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/editions/community.jsp)
- [Data Modeling](http://www.databaseanswers.org/modelling_tools.htm) Tools.
- [Syngraph](http://www.syngraph.me/)

Answer (score 1):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) is the best UML tool I've ever used. It can also do database diagrams, though these are UML-flavour rather than classic ER. Anyway, there's a free trial, so you can see if it meets your needs. I should point out though that no UML/ER design tool is going to make you write better code.

Comment: yes, but they can help in making developers think first and then code. I find that not having any documentation a big problem today.

Comment: It took a while to climb the learning curve in EA, but having done it, I like the tool.  I do both UML and ER diagrams in it, and find the ER good enough that the slight UML flavor of them doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest PowerDesigner from Sybase

http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner

I did not came across a better tool.

Comment: +1 for PowerDesigner. Fabulous tool, but v. pricey.

Answer (score 0):

[MagicDraw](http://www.magicdraw.com/feature_list) has very powerful UML modelling features and some Database design tools as well, which I havent tried. But If they are as good as UML, this is a must have